# Python - Pass a variable in a module to a function in another module

Tags: python, function, selenium, variables, module

I have some code in multiple files like so:

A main module:

```
import TC1
import TC2
```

Some test case modules, which look like:

```
testcase = "Test Case 1"
successmessage = "Specific Success Message for Test Case 1"
errormessage = "Specific Error Message for Test Case 1"

# Run test
if pageLoaded == pageExpected:
    testresult = 0
    logresults()
else:
    testresult = 1
    logresults()
```

And a log results module:

```
def logresults():
    print("Test Results for", testcase,)
        if testresult == 0
            print(testcase, "Passed with", successmessage)
        else:
            print(testcase, "Failed with", errormessage)
```

How can I pass variables from each test case to `logresults`, and have it print the results of each test case as it is run?

Comment: Did you try... importing the log results module, from the test cases (where it's needed); writing `logresults` to have *parameters* that accept the value that need to be passed in; and then using *arguments* in the calls to `logresults` in order to pass that information? It works **the same way as if** the functions were in the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your code.

First, if you import a module with a function that works on globals, it will search for globals that share a namespace. For example, if you have a logresultsmodule with a function logresults and you import it, it will only run on variables that look like this: logresultsmodule.variable

To fix this problem, you will have to change the signature of the function to

```
def logresults(testresult, testcase, successmessage, errormessage): ...
```

and pass the corresponding variables.

The second problem is you call logresults inside a conditional where there is a chance that the testresult variable hasn't been defined yet.

First evaluate the conditional, and then call logresults.

```
from logresultsmodule import logresults
{code that defines testcase, successmessage, errormessage}

if pageLoaded == pageExpected: 
    testresult = 0
else:
    testresult = 1
logresults(testresult, testcase, successmessage, errormessage)
```

So now whenever you import a testcase, the code will run automatically and print the result message.

Comment: This is the concept I was missing. Thanks!